# sine wave drawing using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, snap.svg, trigonometry

I am working on creating a simple snow simulation, but I am failing horribly on the math. Basically, when a snowflake is initialized, it's x position is set randomly somewhere on the svg canvas. Then from there, it falls straight down. It *should* be simulating a sine wave (the x coordinates should move like a sine wave).

I haven't done trig since last year so i'm a bit rusty. `Math.sin()` takes radians I believe, so I multiply by 180, then divide by pi to convert to degrees?

Assume x is the current x position of a snowflake, and width is the width of the canvas.

```
x += (Math.sin(((x/width)*(180/Math.PI)))*width)
```

It kind of works, but it is all over the place. I have a vague idea of what i'm doing, but I can't seem to push the math from my brain to code.

[Here's a JSFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/josueespinosa/yahne/1/)

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
x += A*Math.sin(F*(y/Height)*2*Math.PI);
```

where `A` is the amplitude, i.e. how many pixels you want the flake to shift left and right (note that total shift will be 2*A). F is the frequency, or how often you want the flake to shift left and right (I'd set it at random between 2 and 10 for each flake).